# Limit number guessing game to three attempts

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a game where the user has 3 chances to guess a random number that the program generates. I have this code so far, but I don't know how to get the program to stop after the user inputs 3 out of 3 guesses. If the user is not able to correctly guess in 3 tries, I want the program to say "You loose. The number was ..."

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
class GuessNumber {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Random random = new Random();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int MIN = 1;
        int MAX = 10;
        int comp = random.nextInt(MAX - MIN + 1) + MIN;
        int user;


        do {
            System.out.print("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ");
            user = input.nextInt();

            if (user > comp)
                System.out.println("My number is less than " + user + ".");
            else if (user < comp)
                System.out.println("My number is greater than " + user + ".");
            else
                System.out.println("Correct! " + comp + " was my number! " );
        } while (user != comp);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a counter variable, increase it on each attempt, and print-and-exit when/if counter reaches 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply count the number of attempts and exit the loop once it reaches the threshold. Like that:

```
    int attemptsNum = 0;
    final int maxAttempts = 3;
    do {
        System.out.print("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ");
        user = input.nextInt();

        if (user > comp)
            System.out.println("My number is less than " + user + ".");
        else if (user < comp)
            System.out.println("My number is greater than " + user + ".");
        else
            System.out.println("Correct! " + comp + " was my number! ");
    } while (user != comp && ++attemptsNum <maxAttempts );

    if (attemptsNum == maxAttempts)
        System.out.println("You loose. The number was :" + comp);
```